# Mage_Core_Exception with message 'Cannot retrieve entity config: sales/Array'

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

The following code runs fine under Magento 1.6 but raises a Mage_Core_Exception (message: 'Cannot retrieve entity config: sales/Array') when run under 1.5.0.1. What do I need to do to get this code running under Magento 1.5.0.1?

```
    $results = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
    $results->join(
        array('status_key_table' => 'order_status'), 
        'main_table.status = status_key_table.status', 
        array('status_key_table.label')
    );
```

Thank you,
Ben

Comment: what about error report file in `var/report` directory, did you check which files related this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compare the join() methods between 1.5.0.1 and 1.6.2.0:

```
1.5.0.1: Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract::join()
public function join($table, $cond, $cols='*')
{
    if (!isset($this->_joinedTables[$table])) {
        $this->getSelect()->join(array($table=>$this->getTable($table)), $cond, $cols);
        $this->_joinedTables[$table] = true;
    }
    return $this;
}

1.6.2.0: Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::join()
public function join($table, $cond, $cols = '*')
{
    if (is_array($table)) {
        foreach ($table as $k => $v) {
            $alias = $k;
            $table = $v;
            break;
    ...
```

You can see that 1.5.0.1 doesn't support aliases. Instead, it calls $this->getTable() on the first parameter you pass in -- which should be a string. So, in your case, you'll need to pass in 'sales/order_status' as the first parameter.